# is authentication possible with Onlyoffice?

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, onlyoffice

I run onlyoffice with docker `docker run -i -t -d -p 80:80 onlyoffice/documentserver` and a nginx load balancer which provide ssl encryption.
My question is, **how can i provide a authentication?** without to touch the load balancer.

The Problem is, everybody can use the server.

Comment: I feel like putting basic http auth at nginx would be easier than editing the other dockerfile for adding auth

Comment: The configuration for our load balancer is valid for about 20 systems, it would be really bad to add http auth on the load balancer. It would mess up our configuration system. @cricket_007

Comment: Can't you just add auth to a single route for the document server?

Comment: @cricket_007 is it possible to change the http (nginx?) config within the docker container?

Comment: Assuming you're using the default Nginx container, then, sure. You can volume mount an nginx conf file somewhere under `/etc/nginx/`, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Problem is, everybody can use the server.

We would recommend to enable [JWT](https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/signature/) on the Document Server.
It is supported by the NC connector

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http basic auth works, tested with nextcloud integration:

```
root@e54c225ab8aa:/# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/onlyoffice-documentserver.conf 
include /etc/nginx/includes/onlyoffice-http.conf;
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_tokens off;

  include /etc/nginx/includes/onlyoffice-documentserver-*.conf;
}root@e54c225ab8aa:/#
```

insert eg.:

```
auth_basic           “Administrator’s Area”;
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

and restart nginx `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`